# WooCommerce Templates & How They Work?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've moved the Stock.PHP and Price.PHP files from Templates into my theme WooCommerce -> Single Product folder. Now, I've tried to move this line of code from Stock.PHP into Price.PHP:

```
<p class="stock <?php echo esc_attr( $class ); ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $availability ); ?></p>
```

This is my Stock.PHP file now.

```
<?php
/**
 * Single Product stock.
 * @version 3.0.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

?>

<!-- <p class="stock <?php echo esc_attr( $class ); ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $availability ); ?></p> -->
```

And this is my Price.PHP file.

```
<?php
/**
 * Single Product Price
 * @version 3.0.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

global $product;

?>



<p class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></p>
<p class="stock <?php echo esc_attr( $class ); ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $availability ); ?></p>
```

But for no reason, the Stock is not getting the esc_attr value and the availability of the product. How come this paragraph does get the class and the availability inside the Stock file but not inside the Price file?

Thanks,
Lucian

Comment: The stock is directly displayed in single-product > add-to-cart (in mostly each template product type, so is much more complicated than you can think). For example in `simple.php` template it uses `echo wc_get_stock_html( $product );` and the stock template is called in this function… So this is not going to be as easy as you thought.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec - I see, but how come the stock.php can get the class and the availability and the price.php does not? I'm new to woocommerce and I'm really looking to understand these things. To be honest, all I'm trying to do is to move the stock paragraph below the price, it is actually placed under the meta description, and couldn't find an easier way.

Comment: Instead of removing/copying the code from stock.php, you need to use instead `echo wc_get_stock_html( $product );` for simple products that you will comment in single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php and you will have to paste it in an if statement like `if( $product->is_type('simple') ){ echo wc_get_stock_html( $product ); }` … This need to be done for each product type… But for variable products (and the child product variations) may be it will not work as it is Javascript driven. So This is quiet advanced and complicated. That's all that I can't tell… So good luck